# OpenCV4Android - how to use CLAHE algorithm?

Tags: android, opencv, histogram

I wanted to use CLAHE Algorithm on my image, but I can't find any trace of it in OpenCV4Android tools like Core, Imgproc. Documentation says that it should be in Core class:

http://docs.opencv.org/java/

Could anyone tell me if it's avaliable in Android?

Answer (score 2):

It's in `Imgproc`. But unlike other algorithms which are static methods, it's a **class**:

From OpenCV java docs:

`public class CLAHE`
`extends Algorithm`

Here is the doc:

http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/CLAHE.html

Comment: Is there any way to use this algorithm in java application?
It has a protected constructor.

Comment: It IS in `Imgproc`, but I think it's only in 3.0.0 and up, in 2.4.13.3 the implementation for it is still missing. Which is too bad, since I want to use it for my face recognition preprocessing and wish there was some way to backport it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imgproc.createCLAHE().apply(inmat, outmat);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.